# GNU Prolog - multiplication table

Tags: prolog, append

I have this:

```
:- dynamic(times/3).
mult :- mult([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
mult(Num) :-
    append(L1,[X|R1],Num),
        append(L2,[Y|R2],Num),
            Prod is X*Y,
            assertz(times(X,Y,Prod)),fail.
```

Is there a better way to do this. Create a multiplication table per say with the times(X,Y,XY) facts.

While this does work, i was wondering if there is a way to do it without the fail, because when i don't have the fail on it just comes up with true? for more answers. I just want it to go through all answers without asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a final "fall through" clause to **mult/1** that always succeeds, e.g. mult(_).

Your call to **mult/1** will then successfully build the multiplication table and succeed, allowing you to pose further subgoals after it.

It seems more natural to me to code the **mult/1** predicate using **member/2** rather than **append/3**, but with such a short list it is probably not a big time waster.